# Encountered Internal Server Error No 500 with four possibilities

Tags: 500-internal-error

Four possibilities
1. .htaccess file was misconfigured
2. Permissions on the file requested was misconfigured
3.PHP or CGI code was misconfigured in the file that is requested on site.
4.Site resources are reaching maximum limits.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I found the issue, maybe it helps some one else.

Comment: Lets deduct in this order . 1 . First check whether the site has reached the maximum limits. 2. Delete the plugin WP3- cache ( because it alters the .htaccess file with its required code).3. Reset the code for the .htaccess once you delete the plugin Wp3-cache.
This resolves the issue.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. If you have access to the Apache error log then you would have seen a specific error about .htaccess in there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check your **.htaccess** file.
Check your PHP memory limit; memory should be **64MB** or above. 
you can try  increasing Memory  limit by  adding `define ('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');` in **wp-config.php** file. 
To troubleshoot WordPress errors, you require to enable WordPress Debug, which can be done using **wp-config.php**.
You need to copy and paste the code in wp-config.php file shown below.
`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` .